# iOS allow native html5 player to go into landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, swift, cordova, ionic-framework, video.js

I'm having a strange issue with VideoJS on my Ionic-Cordova app. Everything is working with videojs except that when going fullscreen and attempting to go into landscape mode, the video won't rotate along with the controls. I first thought this had to do with my Xcode project settings but they are set properly and the actual ui of iOS is rotating when I turn the phone, the only thing that does not go landscape is the video and the controls for it.

We recently installed a third party plugin that seems to be the root of the issue but their devs say that it does not control orientation.

Any help would be great, I have already tried various methods of controlling orientation from SO with objective-c to no avail.